# How to list network mounts on Unix mounted via fs-cifs

Tags: unix

We have these QNX boxes that connect to a Windows box via a network share connected via `fs-cifs`. I'm finding that a particular QNX box is no longer connected to the network share I imagined it was and I'd like to see what things it is mounted to. In Window's I can preview all my mounts via the command `net use`. Is there analogous command in QNX or Unix?

Answer (score 1):

I found one way that seems to communicate the mounted network share which is via the df command...

```
/# df
/dev/hd0t179           125033800  12054016 112979784      10%  /
(%COMPUTERNAME%)IPW.IPX.IPY.IPZ    3905421304 1711104120 2194317184      44%  /%ShareName%
/dev/hd0               488397168 488397168         0     100%
```

The second entry is the one that indicated to me I was viewing my network share since I recognized the share name as well as the computer name showing up.

What's troubling however is that QNX only seems to permit one mount, if I execute a second mount the first is no longer visible. Might be the way I'm issuing the fs-cifs command however.